# How to insert values into table before creating cursor for that table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   today       DATE;
   yesterday   DATE;
   traffic     NUMBER;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT dt, traffic
        FROM traffic_diff;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;

   FETCH c1
    INTO today, traffic;

   INSERT
   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

Please suggest how to insert values into table. before creating cursor.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You don't need to explicitly open a cursor in order to perform an INSERT statement.

Comment: i want to insert values for table traffic_diff,before selecting the columns into cursor

Comment: Is there something stopping you from doing that? Are you getting an error message? You don't need an explicit cursor (open or otherwise) to INSERT data into a table.

Comment: Where do the insert values come from?  Why do you need to select them (re-select them) into a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
DECLARE
   today       DATE;
   yesterday   DATE;
   traffic     NUMBER;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT dt, traffic
        FROM traffic_diff;
BEGIN

   insert into traffic_diff(dt,traffic) values(val1,val2);
   commit;

   OPEN c1;

   FETCH c1
    INTO today, traffic;

   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```